# How to split python string the clean way when reading from text

Tags: python, string, parsing

Hi I am reading data from a text file using python and the data file looks like this:

```
   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2022-10-15 17:41:06 D....            0            2  B18DCDT026\0011202208230S3764N
2022-10-04 03:47:42 .....       385474       318714  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S4403\0011202208270S4403-c002.wav
2022-10-08 05:47:12 .....          120          114  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S4406\0011202208270S4406-c002.txt
2022-10-08 05:46:42 .....          323          249  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S4406\0011202208270S4406-c001.txt
2022-09-27 06:40:18 .....       279718       232939  B18DCDT026\0011202208220S4425N\0011202208220S4425-n001.wav
2022-10-04 03:41:16 .....       163572       128530  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S4406\0011202208270S4406-c002.wav
2022-10-04 03:41:16 .....       429162       343197  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S4406\0011202208270S4406-c001.wav
2022-10-08 05:49:42 .....          180          166  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S4406\0011202208270S4406-c005.txt
2022-10-04 04:30:04 .....          186          158  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S1310\0011202208270S1310-c003.txt
2022-10-04 04:31:12 .....          107          103  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S1310\0011202208270S1310-c004.txt
2022-10-04 03:41:16 .....       180196       139644  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S4406\0011202208270S4406-c003.wav
2022-09-27 06:19:52 .....       133470       107564  B18DCDT050\0011202208270S1310\0011202208270S1310-c004.wav
```

I only want to read the name part, but the problem here is a file or folder name can contains a space so I cannot use `.split()`, any suggestion guys?

Comment: Use `maxsplit` parameter of `split` so it won't split more than the number of column, I'd say `maxsplit=5` regarding what you show, but adjust if you don't see the expected result

Comment: You could also use a regex to get the 5th column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a maxsplit and take the last value like

```
name = line.split(maxsplit=5)[-1]
```